# qml stackview: reload top of the stack

Tags: qml, stackview

Is there a way to reload the item at the top of the stack after a pop operation.
Is it always loaded from memory or can I force the page to initialize again.

Comment: You mean you want to 'reload/reset' the item that became the new top item after you call pop?

Comment: yes, I want to reload after pop is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lower pages are kept alive, and a new page is just layered above it. So if you have all the properties of the page properly bound and all signals are properly in place, you would have no need to reload.
Often it is not intended to have it reloaded as you will lose any internal state, such as user input et. al. if you don't always store that information outside of the page.

In case you only want to pause the bindings and re-enable them later, introduce a

```
 property bool isActive
```

and use conditional bindings

```
 property int myProperty: isActive ? someOtherProperty * 5 : 0
```

or

```
 Binding {
     ...
     when: isActive
 }
```

---

If you really want to reload the whole page, you can do that with a `Loader`. Instead of pushing the page directly to the stack, push the `Loader` that loads the page. Then you can just change its `active`-property to reload the page.